# c# Factory Method and protection levels problem

Tags: c#, inheritance, factory, protected

I have a base class and several subclasses derived from that base class.  I also have a static function in the base class that takes some parameters, and instantiates and returns an appropriate subclass based on input parameters ( my factory method.)

Now here's my problem:  I want to ONLY allow instantiation of the subclasses FROM the factory method.  But if I set the constructors of the subclasses to be protected, the base class can't see them.  Is there an access modifier I'm missing that would allow the base class to call the subclasses constructors, but not not allow any other classes to call them?

Internal doesn't look like it will work either...I want to limit access to the subclass constructors to just the base class, there are other classes in the same assembly that should be able to access the base factory method and but not directly instantiate any of the subclasses.

Hopefully there's something really simple I'm missing...

Example:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base CreateChild(string childType)
    {
        if(childType == "A")
            return new ChildA();
        if(childType == "B")
            return new ChildB();

        return null;
    }
}

public class ChildA
{
    protected ChildA() // This doesn't work, since now base class can't call this!
    {
    }
}

public class ChildB
{
    protected ChildB()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the child classes as private nested classes inside Base

Comment: Also, you can make Base and ChildA/B partial, and just declare Child inside Base, and then have another Partial Base and Child were you declare all the code, to keep them seperate.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me.  Wish I could give both you and zsalzbank credit, since you both gave the same answer, and did NOT tell me to just do something totally different like most of the times I go to a forum for help.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring the child classes within the base class?

```
public class Base {
    protected class ChildA {}
    protected class ChildB {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If accessing any *derived* object through the *base* type is a valid scenario (let's say *derived* types only override *base* implementations and do not add new functionality) then the proposed solution of making the *derived* types nested `private` classes (as previous answers propose) is the best solution.

If that's not the case then I think you are falling into a case of *unjustified* complexity. What is the reason why code from your same assembly can not access `ChildA` and `ChildB` constructors? It is after all code you can control, so you can always choose to make / enforce via code review that he initalization is through the factory method.

I understand there is valid reasons to not let external assemblies freely instantiate objects except through a tightly controlled mechanism. In this case just marking the constructors as `internal` would do.

Otherwise, I'm not sure you can achieve what you are pretending without creating a specific assembly just for this *base* class and its *derived* classes. There is definitely no access modifier that would make a static method in a *derived* class only visible from it's *base* class.

Comment: The other answers actually give a very good solution to this...I'd argue it's not unnecessary complexity at all.

I'm using the sublcasses for comparisons.  If they are created from the factory method I know the CORRECT subclass was instantiated, instead of possibly a different sublass that was manually constructed.  I don't want to duplicate a bunch of code to find the best match, so having a factory method really simplifies things for me.

Comment: @SomeGuy: Like my answer states (I was editting I guess when you read it). If the derived types only override base implementation then yes, its a valid solution. But if they were to have added functionality you loose that as you can only call through the base type (specific derived types are unreachable). You did not really specify that in your question. `ChildA a = (ChildA)Base.CreateChild("A");` could have been a valid scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to keep the example simple...and I was in fact commenting as you edited.

My actual program is a poker program where I'm using a base PokerHand class and a bunch of derived specific hands ( FullHouse, Striaght, etc.)  Theres no real functionality in the derived classes, I just want a collection of hands to sort properly and the factory method to figure out what type of hand it is...but obviously I can't have a mistyped hand or things would get very iffy.